# Почему работает на Linux, но не работает на Windows или аномалии wi-fi адаптера

Tags: linux, windows, wifi, tp-link

Из заголовка, уже возникает вопрос а такое вообще возможно? Купил на днях usb wi-fi адаптер, не обратив внимание на то что он для 5Ghz сетей и всё отлично работало правда я сидел на Linux дистрибутиве **Manjaro**, при подключение в usb вход он сам определился и подобрал себе драйвера.

**Wi-fi адаптер**:TP-LINK AC 450 Wireless Nano usb Adapter Model No. Archer T1U

**Standarts**:IEEE 802.11a/n/ac

**Frequency**:5GHz

**Interface**:USB 2.0

Окей он работает под Linux, но когда я загрузился обратно на Windows 10, его конечно не определило, пришлось устонавливать драйвера. Но драйвера с диска не работают, а скаченные с сайта не видят 2.4 GHz сеть. Насколько я понял у меня роутер не работает на частоте 5 GHz. Роутер - Huawei HG8245H.

С Linux я вытащел **инфу по устройству**:

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:0105 TP-Link Archer T1U 802.11a/n/ac Wireless Adapter [MediaTek MT7610U]

MediaTek MT7610U под windows не нашёл.

Настройки Huawei HG8245H:
[image: Wlan basic configuration]
[image: Wlan advanced configuration]

*Прочие: Когда установлены драйвера на Windows непрерывно мигает зелёным цветом и начинает быстро нагреваться, на Linux такого нет. На Linux очень плохой сигнал пришлось подключить через удлинитель и положить напротив антены роуетра чтоб ловил 3 палки, но скорость 15Mbyte+.*

Драйвер под windows брал отсюда https://www.tp-link.com/ru/download/Archer-T1U.html#Driver

Инфа вытащенная с Linux:

```
47: USB 00.0: 0282 WLAN controller
[Created at usb.122]
Unique ID: dwDZ.9E64z84dXG5
Parent ID: ADDn.4Nx_qoDfSd7
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-1.3:1.0
Hardware Class: network
Model: "MediaTek WiFi"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x2357 "MediaTek"
Device: usb 0x0105 "WiFi"
Revision: "1.00"
Serial ID: "1.0"
Driver: "mt76x0"
Driver Modules: "mt76x0"
Device File: wlp0s26u1u3
Features: WLAN
Speed: 480 Mbps
HW Address: 50:3e:aa:43:10:b5
Permanent HW Address: 50:3e:aa:43:10:b5
Link detected: yes
WLAN channels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 36 40 44 46 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136
WLAN frequencies: 2.412 2.417 2.422 2.427 2.432 2.437 2.442 2.447 2.452 2.457 2.462 2.467 2.472 5.18 5.2 5.22 5.23 5.24 5.26 5.28 5.3 5.32 5.5 5.52 5.54 5.56 5.58 5.6 5.62 5.64 5.66 5.68
WLAN encryption modes: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
WLAN authentication modes: open sharedkey wpa-psk wpa-eap
Module Alias: "usb:v2357p0105d0100dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc02ipFFin00"
Driver Info #0:
Driver Status: mt76x0 is active
Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe mt76x0"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
Attached to: #48 (Hub)
```

**Вопрос:** Почему данное устройство работает на Linux на частоте 2.4 GHz а на Windows нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятней всего, в linux используется единый [драйвер](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u) для всех устройств основанных на чипе `MediaTek MT7610`. Сам чип [поддерживает](https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/mt7610u) все стандарты — a/b/g/n/ac. Но инженеры TP-Link решили не реализовывать в своём устройстве поддержку стандартов с частотами 2,4ГГц b/g[/n], например, потому что не смогли впихнуть в корпус отдельной антенны для этого. Соответственно общий драйвер под linux, управляя чипом ищет все сети, но по аппаратным соображениям получает на сетях диапазона 2,4ГГц крайне слабый сигнал, а собственный драйвер TP-Link под win ищет только сети диапазона 5 ГГц и даже не пытается заставить устройство работать в другом диапазоне.

**Дисклеймер:** Я не причастен к разработке этого устройства или какого-либо драйвера для него, а также я в моём распоряжении нет подобного, чтобы доподлинно подтвердить или опровергнуть мои догадки. Так что все утверждения здесь чисто умозрительные.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял что мой роутер не предназаначен для вещания на частоте 5Ghz, я кто му что 802.11n может вещать на 5Ghz. И если не трудно посоветуйте стоит ли пытаться дальше танцевать с бубном чтоб всё заработало на 10 или проще взять другой адаптер ?

Comment: >>*Правильно ли я понял что мой роутер не предназаначен для вещания на частоте 5Ghz*<< — основываясь на беглом гугляже (хотя на нормальные ТТХ я так и не наткнулся), похоже на то... >>*я кто му что 802.11n может вещать на 5Ghz*<< — AFAIK в `n` есть спецификация для обоих диапазонов, но 5ГГц обычно поддерживает только оборудование, которое также поддерживает `ac`... >>*стоит ли пытаться дальше танцевать с бубном чтоб всё заработало на 10 или проще взять другой адаптер ?*<< — если нет спортивного интереса заставить его работать, то я бы взял другой...

Comment: Спасибо за то что потратили на меня своё время!